# Neither .bashrc or .profile are being sourced when I open up a graphical terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I've been setting up users for a project on a remote server. When I log in via x2go and open up a terminal it seems like neither `.bashrc` or `.profile` are run. The `.profile` file has a line containing `source .bashrc`.

However, after opening a terminal if I explicitly log into the user using `su userName` the `.bashrc` file gets run and I can use my environments. The terminal line looks like `sh-4.3$` instead of `userName$` like I'm used to as well. Any ideas what's going on or how I can fix this?

Comment: What "terminal" (`gnome-terminal` / `lxterm` / `xterm` etc.) are you opening, exactly? it sounds like it is running `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`

Comment: It happens across all 'terminals' that I have install lxterm and uxterm

Comment: And what is the users' login shell (as shown by the last field of `getent passwd $USER`)?

Comment: :/home/<userName>:

Comment: OK so how exactly are you creating the users? it looks like no login shell is being defined for them (possibly making terminals default to `/bin/sh`?)

Comment: sudo useradd -d /home/<userName> -m <userName>

Comment: is it reasonable to try to add /bin/sh to the end of the /etc/psswd file

Comment: It would be safer to use `chsh` to set the desired shell. BTW what version of Ubuntu is the remote server running?

Comment: it's running the NITRC (https://www.nitrc.org/) computing environment environment which is built on-top of ubuntu 16.04 (LXDE)

Comment: Thank you this really seems to have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here turned out to be that the user account's configured login shell was not `bash`, and therefore it did not automatically read and run commands from the files `bash` uses. Specifically, no login shell was configured, so the default of `/bin/sh` was used:

> OK so how exactly are you creating the users? it looks like no login shell is being defined for them (possibly making terminals default to `/bin/sh`?)

– [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) [2 days ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170417/neither-bashrc-or-profile-are-being-sourced-when-i-open-up-a-graphical-termina#comment1953335_1170417)

Since that was unintended, the solution, **provided by [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170417/neither-bashrc-or-profile-are-being-sourced-when-i-open-up-a-graphical-termina#comment1953341_1170417)**, was to change the shell to `bash` with [`chsh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/chsh.1.html):

> It would be safer to use `chsh` to set the desired shell. BTW what version of Ubuntu is the remote server running?

– [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) [2 days ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170417/neither-bashrc-or-profile-are-being-sourced-when-i-open-up-a-graphical-termina#comment1953341_1170417)

The system [turned out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170417/neither-bashrc-or-profile-are-being-sourced-when-i-open-up-a-graphical-termina#comment1953342_1170417) to be running Ubuntu 16.04, and like on other Ubuntu releases, [`bash` was available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170417/neither-bashrc-or-profile-are-being-sourced-when-i-open-up-a-graphical-termina#comment1953344_1170417).

---

One way to use the [`chsh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/chsh.1.html) command is like this, with the full path of the desired login shell entered in place of *`shell`*:

```bash
chsh -s shell
```

So, to change one's shell to (or back to) `bash`:

```bash
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Another way is to run `chsh` without arguments, in which it case it runs interactively and the user must enter the name of the shell wanted, or simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the default.

In both usages, `chsh` prompts for the user's password before continuing. This is the user's own password (whether or not the user has the ability to run commands as root with `sudo`). For example, in the interactive usage:

```
ek@Kip:~$ chsh
Password:
Changing the login shell for ek
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
        Login Shell [/bin/bash]:
```

If you see this, it means the password was entered wrongly:

```
chsh: PAM: Authentication failure
```

The shell should be provided as an absolute path (starting with `/`). Only shells listed the file `/etc/shells` can be chosen. One way to display the contents of that file is to run `cat /etc/shells`. It contents depend on which shells have been installed (and may also have been manually modified by system administrators).

*For more information about how different shells use different startup files, see [Where to define aliases: .cshrc or .bashrc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843799/where-to-define-aliases-cshrc-or-bashrc)*